# How to launch native camera with the front facing camera?

Tags: ios, actionscript-3, camera, air

I'm using the [CameraUI](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/media/CameraUI.html#includeExamplesSummary) feature of Adobe Air to launch the Native Photo Camera on iOS 8.
The camera on the devices back is used by default. Is it possible to launch the camera with the front facing camera as a default?

Native camera sample code:

```
package  {
     import flash.desktop.NativeApplication;
     import flash.display.Loader;
     import flash.display.MovieClip;
     import flash.display.StageAlign;
     import flash.display.StageScaleMode;
     import flash.events.ErrorEvent;
     import flash.events.Event;
     import flash.events.IOErrorEvent;
     import flash.events.MediaEvent;
     import flash.media.CameraUI;
     import flash.media.MediaPromise;
     import flash.media.MediaType;

         public class CameraUIStillImage extends MovieClip{

              private var deviceCameraApp:CameraUI = new CameraUI();
              private var imageLoader:Loader; 

              public function CameraUIStillImage() {
                   this.stage.align = StageAlign.TOP_LEFT;
                   this.stage.scaleMode = StageScaleMode.NO_SCALE;

                   if( CameraUI.isSupported )
                   {
                    trace( "Initializing camera..." );

                    deviceCameraApp.addEventListener( MediaEvent.COMPLETE, imageCaptured );
                    deviceCameraApp.addEventListener( Event.CANCEL, captureCanceled );
                    deviceCameraApp.addEventListener( ErrorEvent.ERROR, cameraError );
                    deviceCameraApp.launch( MediaType.IMAGE );
                   }
                   else
                   {
                    trace( "Camera interface is not supported.");
                   }
              }

              private function imageCaptured( event:MediaEvent ):void
              {
                   trace( "Media captured..." );

                   var imagePromise:MediaPromise = event.data;

                   if( imagePromise.isAsync )
                   {
                    trace( "Asynchronous media promise." );
                    imageLoader = new Loader();
                    imageLoader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener( Event.COMPLETE, asyncImageLoaded );
                    imageLoader.addEventListener( IOErrorEvent.IO_ERROR, cameraError );

                    imageLoader.loadFilePromise( imagePromise );
                   }
                   else
                   {
                    trace( "Synchronous media promise." );
                    imageLoader.loadFilePromise( imagePromise );
                    showMedia( imageLoader );
                   }
              }

              private function captureCanceled( event:Event ):void
              {
                   trace( "Media capture canceled." );
                   NativeApplication.nativeApplication.exit();
              }

              private function asyncImageLoaded( event:Event ):void
              {
                   trace( "Media loaded in memory." );
                   showMedia( imageLoader );    
              }

              private function showMedia( loader:Loader ):void
              {
                   this.addChild( loader );
              }

              private function cameraError( error:ErrorEvent ):void
              {
                   trace( "Error:" + error.text );
                   NativeApplication.nativeApplication.exit();
              }
         }
    }
```

Comment: use a classic video, camera, and cameraposition class for that. CameraUI is mostly for android.

Comment: Does the "classic camera" come with the on screen buttons of the "native camera" feature such as auto focus, flash, switch camera?

Comment: no it doesn't so you'll have to make your own. But you get full control of the camera including switching sides.